# jQuery image preload doesnt work first time in FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-animate

I just finished putting together a simple jQuery gallery with some fading transitions as seen [here](http://thechristopherstewart.com/gallery/gallery.html). Everything works fine in all browsers - except that the "image preloading" doesn't work on the first load in FireFox (works in all other browsers). The images stay at 0% opacity in firefox. Not sure why.

Here is the preload code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //--------PRELOAD LOAD IMAGES--------\\
    $('img').load(function() {
        //once image has loaded fade in image
        $(this).animate({opacity : 1.0}, 1000);

        //kill padding on last thumbnail of each line
        $('#headshots img').eq(3).css({'padding-right' : '0'});
        $('#ports img').eq(3).css({'padding-right' : '0'});
        $('#ports img').eq(7).css({'padding-right' : '0'});
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of curiosity, try:

```
$(this).each(function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity : 1.0}, 1000);
});
```

To make your solution more robust, you should consider forcing the load event to fire for each image in the event that it has been cached by the browser, which can prevent it's load event from triggering. You can do this by testing for the `.complete` property:

```
$('img').load(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity : 1.0}, 1000);
    });
    $('#headshots img').eq(3).css({'padding-right' : '0'});
    $('#ports img').eq(3).css({'padding-right' : '0'});
    $('#ports img').eq(7).css({'padding-right' : '0'});
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

I didn't know you could chain like that in jQuery. Would you mind explaining how the last each(function() call at the end of the load function is working?

Thanks!

Comment: @mattelliottIT - the last `.each` iterates over each image, checking that the `.complete` property has been set - and if it has, then manually fire off the `.load` event. Generally, when an image is `.complete`, it's `.load` event will not fire, hence the manual intervention to check that the image has completed, and triggering it's load event accordingly. Imagine that one of the images has already been cached by the browser and is immediately fetched up from the cache without the onload event being triggered. Your `.load` event handler will not fire, so you page will not behave as expected.:)

Comment: Ah Got it.
Thanks for taking the time to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

I have some question about your "firefox firstload fix". I use slightly changed code to eliminate the above described firefox error in connection with the jquery flexslider.

```
$(window).load(function() { 
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",              //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
        slideDirection: "horizontal",   //String: Select the sliding direction, "horizontal" or "vertical"
        slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
        animationDuration: 1500,         //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
        directionNav: false,            //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
        controlNav: false,              //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
        controlsContainer: ".flex-container"
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').load(function() {
        $(this).each(function() {
            /*alert("each func");*/
            /*$(this).animate({opacity : 1.0}, 1000);*/
        });
    }).each(function() {
        if(this.complete) {
            //var src = $(this).attr("src");
            //alert(src);
            $(this).trigger("load");
        };
    });
});
```

1. I put it after the setup of the flexslider. Is this correct/good like that?
2. I dont't get how it works. You explain that if an image comes frome the browser-cache the load event will not fire. But then I wounder if or why "$('img').load(function()" gets fired. I mean, when the event is not fired because the image came from the cache, we can't hook the 'img'.load because i won't be fired.
   Other words: Please explain what happens when a image comes from the cache. What in the code or event "area" fails?

UPDATE: www.ozeankreuzer.de it still fails on first load each day. What's wrong?
error is: document.body is undefined: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31225678/Screenshot%20-%2014.06.2012%20%2C%2003_12_28.png

Comment: Im not familiar with flexslider but I get the feeling it should be inside the doc.ready.
Give that a try. Otherwise there is something somewhere in your code that is causing issues.